# Convert Epoch time in Sqlite (Dbeaver) and parse out time

Tags: sqlite, unix, epoch, dbeaver

I have a dataset with epoch time, but am having difficulty casting it to a timestamp, I also need to parse out the timestamp to add another column just for the time of day, so that I can group data by the time of day the transaction occurred.

I also need to convert to different time zones, from another column (IE, GMT-8 for rows of data, GMT-7 for some, etc etc.)

Example: 
1520555554 is March 8th, 2018 16:32 (Pacific Time Zone, GMT-8)

I need to convert from epoch to time stamp, and create another column parsing out 16:32 as the time of day.

Answer (score 0):

For the last part, use `strftime()` or another one of the [sqlite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). For example,

```
SELECT strftime('%H:%M', timestamp_column, 'unixepoch') FROM ...
```

Dealing with timezones is going to be more complicated. Looks like there's no builtin support for them.